# Does warm water freeze faster than cool water?

Tags: water

I just happened to stumble across a phrase that says so, is it true?

Here is the source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect

Comment: Answer is inside your link, it contains link to a paper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.

Answer taken from a link to a paper in the Wikipedia link provided.

> The Mpemba effect-warm water freezes faster than 
>   cool-was first described in this magazine ten years 
>   ago in an article entitled ‘Cool’ by E B Mpemba and 
>   D G Osborne (Phys. Educ. I969 4 172-5)

[Link to paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0031-9120/14/7/312/pdf/pev14i7p410.pdf)

[image: Image taken from the paper]

Image taken from the paper show a plot.